# parse user input on forms to force capitals on names in php

Tags: php, forms

I have a small function to correct user entries if they do not capitalize their name in a form.

```
<pre>
function fixWords($x){
    // define process
    $x= strtolower($x);
    $x= ucwords($x);
    return $x;
}   
</pre>
```

I am finding that double names and hyphenated names are not getting capitals. What is the best way to split out doubles and hyphenated names to force capitals on those also. Thanks.

Comment: And/or if my answer helped, please accept my answer as correct. Cheers

Comment: Thank you.. I'll try these both and post back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ucfirst()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php) and [preg_replace_callback()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), i.e.:

```
function fixWords($name)
{
    return preg_replace_callback('/\b\w/i', function($matches) {
        return ucfirst(strtolower($matches[0]));
    }, $name);
}

print fixWords("some name");
# Some Name
print fixWords("some-name");
# Some-Name
```

---

[PHP Demo](https://eval.in/785880)

Comment: Thank you.. I'll try these both and post back.

Comment: Pedro and Sterling-- Thank you. I prefer Pedro's version because with the preg_replace_callback() I can add other nuances that also show up from time to time, like 'accent' chars ex. De`Chardin

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the mix:

```
$xArr = explode('-', $x);
$i = 0;
while($i < count($xArr)) {
   $xArr[$i] = ucfirst($xArr[$i]);
   $i++;
}
$x = join('-', $xArr);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php

Comment: I prefer `for()` and `implode()` but this is pretty much the cleanest solution I can think of!

Comment: Thank you.. I'll try these both and post back.

Comment: Pedro and Sterling-- Thank you. I prefer Pedro's version because with the preg_replace_callback() I can add other nuances that also show up from time to time, like 'accent' chars ex. De`Chardin